# R - Pulling out exact values out a data set from a character list

Tags: r, string, list, unique

I am a beginner at R and have just started learning it. I have several list of strings with duplicates that I removed using unique() to create a third list.

```
list1 <- c("AB12", "AB2", "AB3")
list2 <- c("AB1", "AB2", "AB3")
list3 <- unique(c(A,B))
```

I also have a data frame named `dfr` with 2 columns that looks like this:

```
Name  Value
AB1      1
AB2      2
...     ...
```

and so on up to AB30. How do I pull out the rows that exactly match those in `list3`? I tried using a method I found elsewhere that involves using `paste` and `grepl` like this:

```
new_list <- grepl(paste(list3, collapse = "|"), dfr$Name) 
new_dfr <- dfr[new_list,]
```

but the results I get back are not exact matches. For example, instead of giving me a new data table with just the rows `AB1` and `AB12`, I get back a data frame with the row `AB21` in there too. How do I get a data frame with only rows that exactly match those in my character list? I'm not sure if I should be using `grep` or if there's a way to do the same thing with `match` instead.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Psidom's answer should do the trick, but the reason you're not getting what you expect is that your pattern in `grepl` doesn't have any boundaries around each substring of interest.  So, the pattern "AB1" will match "AB12".  To continue on with your paste approach, you could in wrap each entry in `list3` with `\\b`: `paste("\\b", list3, "\\b", sep = "", collapse = "|")`

Answer (score 2):

For exact match, you can just use `%in%` operator to check the *Name* and filter the data frame:

```
dfr[dfr$Name %in% list3, ]
```

Will give you rows whose Names are within `list3`. `dfr$Name %in% list3` gives a logical vector which indicates whether each Name is within `list3`, the logical vector can then be used to filter your data frame, where a TRUE indicates picking up the row and a FALSE indicates dropping the row.

Answer (score 1):

Readable tidyverse and also a readable base R:

```
library(tidyverse)

list1 <- c("AB12", "AB2", "AB3")
list2 <- c("AB1", "AB2", "AB3")
list3 <- unique(c(list1, list2))

df <- data_frame(Name=c("AB1", "AB2"), Value=c(1, 2))

filter(df, Name %in% list3)
## # A tibble: 2 × 2
##    Name Value
##   <chr> <dbl>
## 1   AB1     1
## 2   AB2     2

subset(df, Name %in% list3)
## # A tibble: 2 × 2
##    Name Value
##   <chr> <dbl>
## 1   AB1     1
## 2   AB2     2
```

The `fastmatch` provides a faster `match()` which can be used if `list3` is somewhat large:

```
library(fastmatch)

`%fmin%` <- function(x, table) { fmatch(x, table, nomatch = 0) > 0 }

filter(df, Name %fmin% list3)
## # A tibble: 2 × 2
##    Name Value
##   <chr> <dbl>
## 1   AB1     1
## 2   AB2     2

subset(df, Name %fmin% list3)
## # A tibble: 2 × 2
##    Name Value
##   <chr> <dbl>
## 1   AB1     1
## 2   AB2     2
```

Answer (score 0):

We can also `data.table` with `%chin%` to subset the rows with 'Name' have those values in 'list3'.  It is compact, readable and fast.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dfr)[Name %chin% list3]
#   Name Value
#1:  AB1     1
#2:  AB2     2
```